# Repeat Audio Backgorund In Video file Using ffmpeg

Tags: c#, audio, video, ffmpeg

My program allow user to insert bunch of images and one audio file, then can generate them into a video file. My program also allow user to provide duration for each images.

I am able to adding audio background into video output, but when video length is more longer than audio length, audio is not looping.
Also when audio length is more longer than video length, the video output will show blank till the end of audio.

**Create Video**

```
public bool CreateVideo(string name, List<string> imgs)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)null;
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(this.outputFolder + "\\temp"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(this.outputFolder + "\\temp");
            int num = this.rand.Next(this.delayMin, this.delayMax + 1);
            List<string> stringList = new List<string>((IEnumerable<string>)imgs);
            if (this.randomizeImages)
                this.Shuffle((IList)stringList);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.waterImage) && File.Exists(this.waterImage))
                bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(this.waterImage, true);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.introImage))
            {
                int index = stringList.IndexOf(this.introImage);
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    string str = stringList[index];
                    stringList[index] = stringList[0];
                    stringList[0] = str;
                }
            }
            for (int position = 0; position < stringList.Count; ++position)
                this.ApplyWatermarkImage(stringList[position], position, (Image)bitmap);
            if (bitmap != null)
                bitmap.Dispose();
            string str1 = "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.audioFile))
            {
                str1 = " -i \"" + this.audioFile + "\" -ar 22050 -ab 64k ";
                if (this.GetAudioLength(this.audioFile) > num * stringList.Count)
                    str1 += "-shortest ";
            }
            string str2 = this.outputFolder + "\\" + name + ".avi";
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\sm\\ffmpeg.exe", str1 + "-fflags +genpts -r 1/" + (object)num + " -b 32K -f image2  -i \"" + this.outputFolder + "\\temp\\%3d.jpg\" -vcodec mjpeg -s " + this.width.ToString() + "x" + this.height.ToString() + "  -y -r 30 \"" + str2 + "\"");
            Process process = new Process();
            processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
            process.Start();
            StreamReader standardError = process.StandardError;
            Trace.WriteLine(standardError.ReadToEnd());
            standardError.Close();
            process.WaitForExit();
            return process.ExitCode != 1 && process.ExitCode != -1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("CreateVideo: " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bitmap != null)
                bitmap.Dispose();
            try
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(this.outputFolder + "\\temp"))
                    Directory.Delete(this.outputFolder + "\\temp", true);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

**Get Audio Length**

```
public int GetAudioLength(string path)
    {
        string output = this.GetOutput(path);
        int num = 0;
        if (output == "" || output.Contains("Invalid data found when processing input") || output.Contains("could not find codec parameters"))
            return num;
        string str;
        try
        {
            str = Regex.Match(output, "(?:Duration\\:)(.*?)(?:,)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].Value.Trim();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            str = "";
        }
        if (str != "")
        {
            try
            {
                num = int.Parse(str.Split(':')[0]) * 3600;
                num += int.Parse(str.Split(':')[1]) * 60;
                num += (int)double.Parse(str.Split(':')[2]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        return num;
    }
```

**Get Output**

```
private string GetOutput(string video_file)
    {
        try
        {
            return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\sm\\ffmpeg.exe",
                Arguments = "-i \"" + video_file + "\"",
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            }).StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

I've looked around but couldn't find a solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated.